# How to solve error 1442 : Can`t update table 'tb_name' in stored fuction/trigger in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

```
delimiter $$ 
   create trigger payment_mile_trigger
    after insert on PAYMENT
    for each row
    begin
    if @mileuse = 'all' then
        update customer
        set cust_usedmile = cust_usedmile + cust_currentmile
            and cust_currentmile = 0
        where customer.cust_id = new.cust_id;
    elseif @mileuse > 0 then
        update customer
        set cust_usedmile = cust_currentmile + @mileuse
            and cust_currentmile = cust_currentmile - @mileuse
        where customer.cust_id = new.cust_id;
    end if ;
   end $$
delimiter ;
```

```
delimiter $$ 
   create trigger Booking_trigger3
    before insert on Booking
    for each row
    begin
      declare pay_totalamount int;
      declare time_stamp timestamp;
      declare pay_type varchar(15);
      declare key_id int;
      declare cust_id int;
      
      set pay_totalamount = new.booking_totalamount;
      set time_stamp = current_timestamp();
      set pay_type = @paytype;
      set key_id = null;
      set cust_id = new.cust_id;
      
    if @mileuse = 'all' then
        insert into payment(pay_totalamount,pay_date,pay_type,key_id,cust_id) 
        value ((select cust_currentmile from customer where customer.cust_id=cust_id),
        time_stamp, 'mile',key_id,cust_id);
        insert into payment(pay_totalamount,pay_date,pay_type,key_id,cust_id) 
        value (pay_totalamount-(select cust_currentmile from customer where cust_id=cust_id),
        time_stamp, pay_type,key_id,cust_id);
    elseif @mileuse > 0 then
        insert into payment(pay_totalamount,pay_date,pay_type,key_id,cust_id) 
        value (@mileuse,
        time_stamp, 'mile',key_id,cust_id);
        insert into payment(pay_totalamount,pay_date,pay_type,key_id,cust_id) 
        value (pay_totalamount-@mileuse,
        time_stamp, pay_type,key_id,cust_id);
    else
      insert into payment(pay_totalamount,pay_date,pay_type,key_id,cust_id) 
        value (pay_totalamount,time_stamp, pay_type,key_id,cust_id);
    end if;
   end $$
delimiter ;
```

I created two triggers.

One is a trigger that inserts two data into the payment table if you pay with mileage when making a reservation. (Payment of mileage, the remaining amount is paid by other payment methods)

And the other trigger is to deduct mileage.
If there is an item paid with mileage in the payment table, the mile is deducted from the customer table.

But I get an error:

> Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'customer' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

My guess is that this issue is due to a conflict of the above two triggers. This is because the one is selects data(mileage) from the customer table when all mileage is used, but the other one is updates data(mileage) from customer table.

I found two problems.
The first is that mileage is not deducted from the customer table.

The second problem is that when I set @mileuse = 'all' , I get the same error as the title.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I've edited the content to further elaborate on the problem I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem in a slightly different way.

```
delimiter $$ 
   create trigger Booking_trigger3
    before insert on Booking
    for each row
    begin
      declare pay_totalamount int;
      declare time_stamp timestamp;
      declare pay_type varchar(15);
      declare key_id int;
      declare cust_id int;
      
      set pay_totalamount = new.booking_totalamount;
      set time_stamp = current_timestamp();
      set pay_type = @paytype;
      set key_id = null;
      set cust_id = new.cust_id;

    if @mileuse > 0 then
        insert into payment(pay_totalamount,pay_date,pay_type,key_id,cust_id) 
        value (@mileuse,
        time_stamp, 'mile',key_id,cust_id);
        insert into payment(pay_totalamount,pay_date,pay_type,key_id,cust_id) 
        value (pay_totalamount-@mileuse,
        time_stamp, pay_type,key_id,cust_id);
    else
      insert into payment(pay_totalamount,pay_date,pay_type,key_id,cust_id) 
        value (pay_totalamount,time_stamp, pay_type,key_id,cust_id);
    end if;
   end $$
delimiter ;
```

I deleted 'if @mileuse = all then ...'

```
select @mileuse := '0';
select @mileuse := 
    (select cust_currentmile from customer
        where cust_id = @custid); # all mile pay
```

And I decided to split the variable in two.

This doesn't seem like a fundamental solution, but it was the best way to implement it.